# Characterizing finite convex combinations of ergodic probability measures

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $T: X \to X$ an invertible continuous map.

Recall that $T$ is *ergodic* with respect to a $T$-invariant probability measure $\mu$ if and only if any $T$-invariant function in the space $L^2(X, \mu)$ of square-integrable functions with respect to $\mu$ is constant almost everywhere.

Is there any simple property of this kind that characterizes when a $T$-invariant probability measure $\mu$ is a *finite convex combination* of ergodic probability measures?

A reference to any other characterizations of finite convex combinations of ergodic probability measures would also be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps something like saying that every $T$-invariant function has essentially finite range, i.e. there is a $\mu$-full measure subset on which the function has finite range.

Comment: $T$- invariant measures form a convex set of measures whose extreme points are ergodic measures.

Comment: @LeeMosher sounds like an interesting idea - any chance you could elaborate on the proof that this is true for $T$-invariant functions in $L^2(X, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is a finite convex combination?

Comment: @OliverDiaz That's correct. This doesn't imply any measure is a finite convex combination of ergodic measures, however.

Comment: A comment that may be useful. Suppose $\mu$ is a finite convex combination $\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\mu_i$ of ergodic probability measures $\mu_i$. These are all mutually singular. In particular, I believe this implies $f \in L^2(\mu)$ if and only if $f \in L^2(\mu_i)$ for all $i$.  Now if $f$ is $T$-invariant, this implies it is $\mu_i$-a.e. constant for every $i$.

Comment: @4294967296 I think what Lee Mosher said is true. I could be wrong, but here are my thoughts. There's always the ergodic decomposition of a measure; if $\mu$ is not a _finite_ convex combination, then you can construct a $T$-invariant function in $L^2(\mu)$ that does not have finite range (I think... though you can definitely do arbitrarily large finite range).